# Not able to run selenium java script using Selenium(3.11), GeckoDriver(0.24.0), Firefox(57 version)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, gecko

Not able to run selenium javascript using Selenium(3.11), GeckoDriver(0.24.0), Firefox(57 version):

> Getting java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Feb 12, 2019 6:49:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()` 1549977563169   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.CC0uDeBQr5aF" Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath 1549977563829 Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath [Child 16780, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346 [Child 16780, Chrome_ChildThread] WARUnable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath 1549977565363 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54976 1549977565426   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session 1549977565494   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 4294967297 Feb 12, 2019 6:49:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C**

Comment: Does this file exist? `C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath`

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
         capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + pathDriver + "geckodriver.exe");
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
      // Opening the application url
      SeleniumUtils.getDriver().navigate().to(String.valueOf(CONFIG.getProperty("applicationURL")));

Comment: folder "C:\Users\VINNAKP\AppData\Local\openvr" is not present

Comment: That's your issue then

Comment: what can i do to resolve this ?

Comment: Look into why the files are not there and why selenium is looking for them ?

Comment: I can see **`Detected dialect: W3C`** in the trace logs which signals _...all is well..._ till that time. Update the question with the error trace logs

Comment: Updated Selenium to (3.6), Gecko Driver to (0.24.0) and Firefox to (65.0).. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Selenium to (3.6), Gecko Driver to (0.24.0) and Firefox to (65.0).. it worked.